# wpf charting X axis doesn't come properly in respect to data and making over crouded

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

My chart contains a series of 5 line series. Each line with approx 1001 dots. The data of each line is somewhat like this X values from 0 to 1000 and Y values from 0 to 5. My xml is :

```
<DVC:Chart Name="siReturnChart" Title="Si Return" LegendTitle="Legend" Width="850" Height="450">
<!-- Add Title on Y axis and X Axis -->
<DVC:Chart.Axes>
     <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="Chemical Concentration" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Location="Left" FontWeight="Bold" />
     <DVC:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" Title="Production time (days)" Location="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
</DVC:Chart.Axes>

<DVC:Chart.Series>
     <DVC:LineSeries Name="set1layer1Chart" Title="Set 1 Layer 1" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}"  />
     <DVC:LineSeries Name="set1layer2Chart" Title="Set 1 Layer 2"  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}" />
     <DVC:LineSeries Name="set1layer3Chart" Title="Set 1 Layer 3"  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}" />
     <DVC:LineSeries Name="set1layer4Chart" Title="Set 1 Layer 4"  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}" />
     <DVC:LineSeries Name="set1layer5Chart" Title="Set 1 Layer 5"  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}" />
      <DVC:LineSeries Name="set1wellChart" Title="Set 1 Whole Well"  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}" />
```

The result of the chart is :

[image: Result of Chart]

Why the X axis show like this and not the numbers from 0 to 1000 ?? Due to the X axis, the Y axis is also not shown properly and the center of X axis also looks somewhat weird.

Where am I going wrong ? Any idea how do I correct this !!!!

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use a `LinearAxis` instead of a `CategoryAxis`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following line in DVC::Chart.Axes

```
<DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Location="Bottom" Interval="100" />
```

and things got better. The issue was on X Axis numbers from 0 to 1000 was displaying as it wasn't fitting on 1 line so it was coming on 3 lines messing up the display. By adding interval of 100, the dots are coming properly.